# Autofac Resolve an object which is not in Presentation Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

I am using Autofac to resolve objects and I dont want to use **constructor injection** everytime in classes. Therefore I defined a base class but **property injection** didn't solve my problem. Everytime when I tried to reach this property on my base class from derived class, It is null.

For an example

```
public abstract class Service
{
    public static IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
}
```

I have a base class which name is service.

```
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.Register(c => Service.UnitOfWork = c.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>());
```

And my registration like on above.

I have two question about it,

1. Can defining UnitOfWork property as static be dangerous?
2. How can I resolve IUnitOfWork easily?

Comment: *"I dont want to use constructor injection everytime [...]"*  Why not?

Comment: As I said on above. I want to prevent from  implementing a new constructor in derived classes everytime.

Comment: *"I want to prevent from implementing a new constructor in derived classes everytime."* Why?

Comment: There is an implementation costing and I am trying to escape from unnecessary memory consumption.

Comment: [That ought not to be a concern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely should consider the costructor injection pattern again and folow the advice of Mark. However to make your approach work you can do something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<ServiceImpl>().As<Service>()
        .OnActivated(e => Service.UnitOfWork = e.Context.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>());
    var container = builder.Build();
    var service = container.Resolve<Service>();
    Console.WriteLine(Service.UnitOfWork);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here `ServiceImpl` is a derived type from `Service`. As for your first question, public static fields are global variables, it is not a good idea(at all) to store UnitOfWork in this way. Moreover the whole idea of [UnitOfWork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) contradicts with that. At least it would be better to make `UnitOfWork` instance property, protected it of assigning more then once and dispose it explicitlyin `ServiceImpl.Dispose`.

UPD: Additional example for instance property injection approach:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceImpl>().As<Service>()
            .OnActivated(e => e.Instance.UnitOfWork = e.Context.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>());
        var container = builder.Build();
        var service = container.Resolve<Service>();
        Console.WriteLine(service.IsUnitOfWorkInjected);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public abstract class Service : IDisposable
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork
    {
        protected get => _unitOfWork;
        set
        {
            if (_unitOfWork == null)
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (_unitOfWork == null)
                    {
                        _unitOfWork = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsUnitOfWorkInjected => UnitOfWork != null;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _unitOfWork?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Dmitry, thanks for your contribution, after advice of Mark, I checked the implementation which I wrote, It is definitely wrong approach with static property.
The thing is I was trying avoid forgetting the injection of one of these service classes and recreating their constructor method to send resolved unitOfWork property to base constructor everytime.Also, If I choose the constructor injection approach, I need to recreate constructor method in every derived class.  So what I need ? I just want to inject one time and resolve the unitOfWork property with any initialize of service class.

Comment: Onur, please take a look on additinal example.

Comment: Dimitry, thank you so much. That was what I want. Do you think that it can bring more depencies?

Comment: I mean, Can this implementation bring more dependencies?

Comment: Of cource you should add similar registration with `OnActivated` callback for every derived service class.